# Not able to find issue : Using iplib-js for general ip configuration functions , invalid ip returning valid

Tags: javascript, validation

Can you help me finding where am i going wrong since  i am new to javascript. 
i am trying to use iplib-js for common functions related to ip configuration . Issue is when i tried to validate the invalid ip , its validate function returning true .

library : https://code.google.com/p/iplib-js/

Please  try this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/wjUXwczL7NEnIsk20ET7

i back traced the functions -> these block are being used :

observed its returning 0 for invalid characters after parsing thus skipping validate condition :

```
var IPv4 = NetworkAddress.extend({
    constructor:function(address) {
    this.base(address,".");
 },

 validate:function() {
    /*
     * Returns true if the normalized IP address is a valid IPv4 address
     */
    var res = true;
    this.iter(function(p) {
        if(p < 0 || p > 255) {
            res = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    //console.log(res);
    return res;
  },
  iterbits:function(callback) {
    /*
     * Iterate over each bit of the IP address and runs the callback
     * Also passes the index to the callback as well
     */
    var b = this.toBin();
    for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        if(callback(parseInt(b[i]),i) === false) break;
        }
      },
   normalize:function() {
    /*
     * Uses the raw IP address and converts it into a standard IPv4 address
     */
    var p = this._address.split(this._separator);
    while(p.length < IPv4.PARTS) p.push("0");
    for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        while(p[i].length < 3) p[i] = "0"+p[i];
    }
    return p.join(this._separator);
    },
```

Also for parsing this block is being used :

```
    iter:function(callback,radix) {
      /*
       * Provides a way to iterate over the parts of the IP address.
       * Passes the each part to the callback, and the index.
       * Use radix to specify which output format you require (see parts for       
       */
      var p = this.parts(radix);
     for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        if(callback(p[i],i) === false) break;
      } 
        },  
    parts:function(radix) {
     if(!radix) radix = 10;
     var p = this.normalize().split(this._separator);
     for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        p[i] = parseInt(p[i]);
        if(radix!==10) p[i] = p[i].toString(radix);
     }
      return p;

     return this.normalize().split(this._separator);
       },
```

This is my HTML :

```
   <script>
            function myFunction() {
               var ip = new IPv4("a.x.d");
               document.write(ip);
            document.write("<br>");
            var ip_norm = ip.normalize();   //"192.168.000.100"
            document.write(ip_norm);
            document.write("<br>");

            var checkip = ip.validate();
            document.write(checkip);

               }
      </script>     

    </head>

   <body onload="myFunction()">
    <div>testing</div>
   </body>
```

Comment: During further digging , found its converting 00d to 0 in parseInt() in parts:function(radix) .So in validate(value>255 and value<0 condtion )  returns true . can anybody suggest any changes so that it detects normal invalid ip scenariors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't want to touch anything in this library , so using this temporary solution

```
 parts:function(radix) {
       if(!radix){
                console.log("setting redix 10");
                radix = 10;
                }
        // ***added  bad fix here*** 
        // ***only enter when redix 10 (my scenarioes)
            if(radix === 10){
             var p = this.normalize();
             var ipformat = /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/;  
                 if(p.match(ipformat))  
                 {  
                console.log("********  VALID IP   ************");
                 }  
                 else  
                 {  
                 console.log("********** INVALID IP  ***********");
                    // if invalid make everything 256.256.256.256 so that it get caught in original validate
                    var p = this.normalize().split(this._separator);
                    for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {

                            p[i] = 256;



                    }

                    return p;


                 }  

            }
    // this is normal routine to be followed for error checking if redix is not 10 ,or valid ip (skipped from regx used)            
    var p = this.normalize().split(this._separator);
    for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
                console.log("inside converter part = " +i);
             console.log("before parsing");        
            console.log(p[i]);
        p[i] = parseInt(p[i]);
                    console.log("after parsing"); 
                    console.log(p[i]);
        if(radix!==10)
                      { console.log("only if redix not 10");
                          p[i] = p[i].toString(radix);
                          console.log(p[i]);
                      }

    }
            console.log("returning p");
            console.log(p);
    return p;



    return this.normalize().split(this._separator);
}
```